# Convert faulty Webpage/Excel to proper Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-11, apache-tika

I have an app that automatically processes a range of excel files but i have one issue. For some files I have what seems to be an html file with a .xls file extension (opening in excel gives corrupt warning and resaving shows it wants to save as an html).

When using Apachi POI:

```
try (Workbook wkbk = WorkbookFactory.create(myCorruptFile)) {
//myCorruptFile is of type File
```

This fails to process with apache poi NotOLE2FileException error below

```
Invalid header signature; read 0x0A0D3E6C6D74683C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document, { }
```

If I manually resave as a .xls the file will process appropriately, but is there a way to detect and resave/convert this file via java 11? Manually converting the files isn't an option for me as opposed to an automated one.

`myCorruptFile.getContentType()`
Gives content type as:

> application/vnd.ms-excel

And using Apache Tika gives detected type as:

`tika.detect(myCorruptFile.getBytes())`

> text/html

(My maven pom has no filtering)

Comment: You're not sharing the error, nor your code so it is hard to say. Please share the error and the code you're doing so far. Hint: If you're getting an error, just catch the error, if an error arises you can say that you need to resave/convert.

Comment: I've added the error. The code errors after this workbook code is run as a try catch resource

Comment: Updated outputs, mixed up with different file. Post should be up to date now sorry

Comment: `0A0D` obviously suggests that you took a binary file and saved it as a text file. You can _try_ to convert `\r\n` into `\n`'s and then open your file.

Comment: It seems to be a badly converted html given tika type is "text/html". Wouldnt it be best to try programmatically resaving like the manual method? Any advice?